# How can I multiply two Eigen::DiagonalMatrix and ad the result to an Eigen::SparseMatrix?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, diagonal

I'm trying to write a solver for a linear system, and coming from Matlab/NumPy and the like, I find Eigen's types a bit limited.

My current issue resolves around this:

```
D * DD + S
```

Where `D` and `DD` are of type `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>` and `S` is an Eigen::SparseMatrix`.

Is there an (efficient) way to do this? It seems rather basic so I must be missing something. I'm willing to give up `D` and `DD` being `DiagonalMatrix` and them being `SparseMatrix` instead, as long as the above expression is complicated too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sparse matrix `S` already has non-zero coefficients along the diagonal you can do:

```
S.diagonal() += D.cwiseProduct(DD);
```